# FsYacc filename.targets

Tags: f#, fsyacc

I'm trying to specify an output folder for the FsYacc and FsLex compilers. I can see that there are some variables "FsYaccOutputFolder" and "FsLexOutputFolder" given in the FsLexYacc.targets

I do have not that much experience with .targets files, but can understand the general structure of it.

where should I define these variables and how? my first thought was as in the .fsproj file like you declare "otherflags" but it doesn't seems to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be added in the `.fsproj` file. Can you try adding like this :

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <FsYaccOutputFolder>Path to FsYaccOutput</FsYaccOutputFolder>
  <FsLexOutputFolder>Path to FsLexOutput</FsLexOutputFolder>
</PropertyGroup>
```